# Change NameValuePair separator from '=' to ':'

Tags: java, android, httprequest

I am trying to send a `HttpPost` request, and to do this, from what I understand, you do this:

```
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri[0]); 
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
                nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("{\"UserName\"", "\"michigan\""));
                nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("\"Password\"", "\"fanaddicts\""));
                nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("\"DeviceHarwareId\"", "\"NW58xfxz/w+jCiI3E592degUCL4=\""));
                nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("\"DeviceTypeId\"", "\"1\"}"));
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));

                response = httpClient.execute(post); 

                Log.i("Feed Response", "Feed: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()); 

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The problem I'm having is that the entity looks like this:

```
[{"UserName"="michigan", "Password"="fanaddicts", "DeviceHarwareId"="NW58xfxz/w+jCiI3E592degUCL4=", "DeviceTypeId"="1}]
```

But due to the way the server is set up, I need it to look like this:

```
[{"UserName":"michigan", "Password":"fanaddicts", "DeviceHarwareId":"NW58xfxz/w+jCiI3E592degUCL4=", "DeviceTypeId":"1}]
```

You will notice that rather than equal (=) signs, there are colons (:) separating the key/value pairs.

My is question is: How do I fix this?

Comment: Consider using [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) instead of UrlEncodedFormEntity -- since it looks like you want a JSON string, not a URL encoded string.

Comment: @jedwards: why don't you write this as an answer?

Comment: @jedwards make your comment an answer and I'll accept. It worked. Great idea. Thanks.

Comment: @Blaine: Great, happy to have helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) instead of UrlEncodedFormEntity -- since it looks like you want a JSON string, not a URL encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to serialize the json string into a dictionary.  The json structure data than can be accessed by dictionary indices.